# AccuRev - Change the AccuRev issue number for a transaction that used a wrong issue number

Tags: version-control, accurev

Accidently promoted a file with a wrong issue number. Is it possible to change the issue number in AccuRev for that transaction? Note that the stream that i promoted is not enabled with Change package. Appreciate if any help on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Open the issue you accidentally used -> Click on Changes tab -> Select elements -> Right click -> Send to Issue -> Pick correct issue.

This will associate those changes with the correct issue.

Now you will select this elements again from the wrong issue -> Right click -> Select elements -> Remove.

This will disassociate those changes from the wrong issue.

Comment: I tried to do your suggestion, but I didn't get the files in the Changes tab which are promoted for the stream ( Stream is not enabled with Change package ) in the issue that I used accidentally. I'm unsure is there any other way ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: My mistake, I missed the change package disabled comment.  In that case, you can not edit a comment to  change the issue number of the transaction.

Comment: AccuRev history is permanent, meaning that the details of any transaction cannot be changed after the fact.